# Concatenar $+string para hacer llamada a objeto PHP

Tags: php

¿Es posible concatenar el símbolo $ + string para llamar a un objeto en PHP?

Báscamente necesito hacer esto:

```
    <img src="<?= '$'.response ? $explode('-',$this->lang())[0] : '' ?>" target=""  title="<?=$title?>" alt="<?=$AltText?>">
```

El objeto se llama $es, $en

No se si esto es posible, gracias por la ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Las comillas dobles facilitan muchas cosas en PHP, por ejemplo, puedes poner variables dentro de comillas dobles, combinando con texto plano sin necesidad de concatenar. Sea como sea, no veo dónde usarías `$en` y `$es` en tu código ¿? Considera poner un ejemplo mínimo y verificable para que el problema se entienda en su conjunto y podamos ayudarte de la mejor manera.

Comment: Debes poner valores de ejemplo de cada cosa que has puesto en tu pregunta. ¿Que es `response`? ¿Que es $this->lang()? ¿Que contienen $es y $en? ... a mi me da que sí seria posible pero debes explicarte mejor pues quizás lo que yo pienso no tiene que ver con lo que quieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible hacer esa llamada desde `php`.
Lo que deberías hacer es almacenar el valor de la ruta en una variable usando un condicional y luego llamar al `src` de la imagen imprimiendo el valor de la variable. Algo similar a esto:

```
<?php
$lenguaje = "es";
$ruta = "";
if ($lenguaje == 'es'){
    $ruta="/img/logoes.png";
}else{
    $ruta="/img/logoen.png";
}
?>
<img src="<?php echo $ruta;?>" alt="" srcset="">
```

o directamente imprimir el valor de la ruta concatenando el valor de la variable, de esta manera:

```
<?php
$lenguaje = "es"; //aquí tomas el valor de la variable
$ruta="/img/logo".$lenguaje.".png"; //sería "/img/logoen.png" o "/img/logoes.png" depende el valor de $lenguaje
?>
<img src="<?php echo $ruta;?>" alt="" srcset="">
```

espero te sirva de referencia.

Comment: @LiloYStich asi mismo es, realmente no es posible hacer este tipo de concatenación